# Webhook subscription has been disabled and I can't turn it back on

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, messenger

So I was integrating my Dialogflow bot into messenger was working fine , bot is replying from messenger  , and  I shut the dialogflow integration for a while , and then my webhook has been disabled by facebook saying

```
Your Webhooks subscription for callback URL https://bots.dialogflow.com/facebook/07ab3702-95e7-49c3-ac56-9e9d4c4cb1a6/webhook has not been accepting updates for the past 1 hour. This subscription has been disabled. To reactivate, just make a POST request with the same parameters or visit the Webhooks tab in the app dashboard. Learn More about Webhooks.
```

I reactivated my dialogflow integration , added the callback url and token,  but still it won't reply to the bot's messages in messenger. also in the webhook tab
The "messages" and the "messaging_postback " subscription option isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

eh , you just have to unsubscribe to the page in the messenger - > settings section and subscribe again

[image]

got it fixed